# does SQL automatic backup runs even the machine/server is offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I am wondering if the SQL jobs like automating the database backup runs even the machine/server is offline?

Comment: Could you share why you're wondering that? Are you troubleshooting some problem with your backup jobs?

Comment: What exactly does "offline" mean? Disconnected from the internet? Disconnected from your LAN? Powered off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No but you can create a script or a cron job that can take a copy of the files:

- `Database_Name.mdf`
- `Database_Name.ldf`

Such files are stored under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` and are the actual database.

So if you take a copy of those two files and zip them together we can say that you took a backup of the database.

Try to bring those two files on another machine and **attach** them to test if ti works ;)

Answer (score 1):

No SQL Jobs cannot run without the SQL Server & the SQL Agent Service running